# BTSCS data in R: create t

Tags: r, events, duration

Suppose I have the following data frame df:

```
   id year  y
1   1 1990 NA
2   1 1991  0
3   1 1992  0
4   1 1993  1
5   1 1994 NA
6   2 1990  0
7   2 1991  0
8   2 1992  0
9   2 1993  0
10  2 1994  0
11  3 1990  0
12  3 1991  0
13  3 1992  1
14  3 1993 NA
15  3 1994 NA
```

Code to create the df:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
year<-c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994)
y<-c(NA,0,0,1,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA,NA)
df<-data.frame(id,year,y)
```

I want to create the following vector t that measures the duration an observation has been at risk until an event occurs (y=1) or the last entry of an observation (equal to right censoring):

```
   id year  y  t
1   1 1990 NA NA
2   1 1991  0  1
3   1 1992  0  2
4   1 1993  1  3
5   1 1994 NA NA
6   2 1990  0  1
7   2 1991  0  2
8   2 1992  0  3
9   2 1993  0  4
10  2 1994  0  5
11  3 1990  0  1
12  3 1991  0  2
13  3 1992  1  3
14  3 1993 NA NA
15  3 1994 NA NA
```

Any help is highly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution which will also update your data set by reference

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(y), t := seq_len(.N), id][]
#     id year  y  t
#  1:  1 1990 NA NA
#  2:  1 1991  0  1
#  3:  1 1992  0  2
#  4:  1 1993  1  3
#  5:  1 1994 NA NA
#  6:  2 1990  0  1
#  7:  2 1991  0  2
#  8:  2 1992  0  3
#  9:  2 1993  0  4
# 10:  2 1994  0  5
# 11:  3 1990  0  1
# 12:  3 1991  0  2
# 13:  3 1992  1  3
# 14:  3 1993 NA NA
# 15:  3 1994 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be

```
df$t <-  with(df, ave(!is.na(y), id, FUN=cumsum)*NA^is.na(y))
df
#  id year  y  t
#1   1 1990 NA NA
#2   1 1991  0  1
#3   1 1992  0  2
#4   1 1993  1  3
#5   1 1994 NA NA
#6   2 1990  0  1
#7   2 1991  0  2
#8   2 1992  0  3
#9   2 1993  0  4
#10  2 1994  0  5
#11  3 1990  0  1
#12  3 1991  0  2
#13  3 1992  1  3
#14  3 1993 NA NA
#15  3 1994 NA NA
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(t=replace(y, !is.na(y), seq(na.omit(y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `btcs()` command from Dave Armstrong's packages `DAMisc`.

```
df <- btscs(df, "y", "year", "id")
```

That will spit out your original dataset along with a column 'spell' which is the number of time units since the last event.